# Porting Android on embedded platforms with software rendering

Tags: android, opengl-es, porting

I am working on a project which need porting Android-7.0 on embedded platforms. I know the key to porting: implement specific HW drivers and corresponding HALs. When deal with the mali-400 GPU, I should transplant the GPU driver, OpenGL ES libs and UMP(Unified memory provider), but I only want to use software rendering which do not need a real GPU for simplicity.

I set some propertise in init.rc which forcing Android to load the libGLES_android.so:

> setprop ro.kernel.qemu 1
>
> setprop ro.kernel.qemu.gles 0

It works! but the system failed in choosing a suitable EGLconfig, and restart surfaceflinger. Logs are as follow:

```
I/SurfaceFlinger( 1056): SurfaceFlinger is starting
I/SurfaceFlinger( 1056): SurfaceFlinger's main thread ready to run. Initializing graphics H/W...
D/libEGL  ( 1056): Emulator without GPU support detected. Fallback to software renderer.
D/libEGL  ( 1056): loaded /system/lib64/egl/libGLES_android.so
W/gralloc ( 1056): page flipping not supported (yres_virtual=1080, requested=2160)
I/gralloc ( 1056): using (fd=11)
I/gralloc ( 1056): id           = simple
I/gralloc ( 1056): xres         = 1920 px
I/gralloc ( 1056): yres         = 1080 px
I/gralloc ( 1056): xres_virtual = 1920 px
I/gralloc ( 1056): yres_virtual = 1080 px
I/gralloc ( 1056): bpp          = 32
I/gralloc ( 1056): r            = 16:8
I/gralloc ( 1056): g            =  8:8
I/gralloc ( 1056): b            =  0:8
I/gralloc ( 1056): width        = 305 mm (159.568100 dpi)
I/gralloc ( 1056): height       = 171 mm (159.895081 dpi)
I/gralloc ( 1056): refresh rate = 60.00 Hz
W/hwcomposer( 1056): hwcomposer module not found
W/SurfaceFlinger( 1056): no suitable EGLConfig found, trying a simpler query
E/SurfaceFlinger( 1056): no suitable EGLConfig found,giving up
```

Hwcomposer module seems not must. My questions are:

> 1. The method to use software rendering is right?
> 2. Why can't a suitable EGLConfig be found? It seems that I cannot control the procedure of choosing one.
> 3. What can I do, to turn on hardware rendering based on a real GPU?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android no longer supports software-only rendering; a real GPU and OpenGL ES implementation is a hard requirement.

Comment: Why ? I searched on google,  and find nothing about this . please talk more about this if you know some details .

Comment: The UI rendering in Android used to use a subset of OpenGL ES 1.1, which Google has a software emulated layer for, so even if applications didn't work the UI would be rendered correctly. OpenGL ES 1.1 is basically obsolete, so the UI rendering long since moved to OpenGL ES 2.x, which they don't have enmulation for (with programmable shaders it's too complex to emulate efficiently).

Comment: Thx! I know there exist a mesa library support opengl es 2.0 software rendering, It might help.